# Finding unique values in a data file based on two columns

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu, awk

I have a file in Unix like this

```
name1 text text 123432re text
name2 text text 12344qp text
name3 text text1 134234ts text
name3 text text2 134234ts text
```

I want to find all the different types of values in the 3rd column for all user names, lets say `name1`, `name2` and `name3`.

Like below:

```
name1 1
name2 1
name3 2
```

How can I get the required result?

Comment: this has been asked many times and it is quite basic awk. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text in the columns before the 4th column cannot contain spaces, the following should do it with `gawk`:

```
gawk '{++vals[$1][$3];}
  END {for (u in vals) {
       c = 0;
       for (t in vals[u]) { ++c; };
       print u" "c;}
}' yourfile
```

(Note, `gawk` supports multidimensional arrays, while standard `awk` doesn't, so the same solution won't work with standard `awk`.)

Comment: Useless use of cat award! Also, awk doesn't support 2D arrays, so this won't work.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Thanks, my mistake. I haven't noticed that the question was marked only as a standard awk question. Still, a gawk solution might be helpful too.

Comment: @lp_ Thank you very much. Your gawk has solved my requirement. Once again thank you very very much